# Add data present in columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column here which is a simple example of my problem

```
COLUMN1
1
2
```

How would I add the two numbers in COLUMN1

Comment: Well what would i do for varchar

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Comment: I'm sorry about that.i really am. Well it there are varchars in there i want to add two varchars as in 'a'+'b'=ab,or if ther are intigers i want to add them as 2+2=4.

Comment: And how do you know which varchars to add, and which integers to sum up? You want to do this over the entire table?? Or just a few rows?? You're still not being very clear as to what you're trying to do ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still not very clear on what you're trying to do - if you want to SUM up the numeric values from your table, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(Column1 AS INT))
FROM    
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 1
```

This will just sum up all the numeric values over the whole table.

Concatenating together all the non-numeric values is a bit trickier - you'll have to use something like this `FOR XML PATH('')` "trick" to get this done:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        (SELECT '#' + Column1
         FROM dbo.YourTableNameName
         WHERE ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 0    
         FOR XML PATH('')), '#', '')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much marc_s.My problem is solved.You're a lifesaver.but would you be kind enough to elaborate on the     FOR XML    part

Comment: @deception1: see [this Simple-Talk article for more info](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT YourTableName(Column1)
VALUES(1), (2)
```